# Rename third party shared library has no effect?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a library that is provided by a third party, the file name is libPXTrader.so. But I want to rename it to trader.so in my project. So I just renamed it. The weird things is that after I compiled my main file using

```
gcc main.o third_party/lib/trader.so -o main
```

the executable file main is still link to libPXTrader.so.
using command

```
ldd main
```

It shows that libPXTrader.so cannot be found. I used strings trader.so and find the string libPXTrader.so, I guest this shared library name is hardcoded into the so file. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me answer my own question. In libPXTrader.so, there is a .dynamic section, where there is an optional field called SONAME, if SONAME is set to an non-empty string, even if you rename libPXTrader.so, the main file is still linked to libPXTrader.so.